How to see if object is in a list
How do I in Node.JS check if a object like {idx: X, idy: y} in is in a list?
I've tried with .index and other things, but I think because it is a object with multiple values it fail.
My list has the format:
list = [{idx: xyz, idy: zyx}, {idx: qwe, idy: ewq}, ...]


Loop your array and check if current element matches expected

I've tried with .index why? there's absolutely no reason to use .index since it's not what you're looking for. Show what you tried. it is a JSON-object there is no such thing. What you have is an Object ... JSON is and always will be a String

What you call "JSON objects" don't exist. A value is either JSON (a string type, since it's textual encoding of data. Same as XML which is also textual encoding) or an object in which case it's not JSON because it's not a string. See What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?
